# Textfield issue in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a textfield in my view controller under the textfield I have used a table view to show data in it and when we click any data from table view it shows in the textfield. Now when I press any cell of table view to show that data in text field it shows fine but textfield do not catch the data from table view it only send data manually written on the textfield. it shows me this in console,

```
<UITableViewCell: 0x7f9dad0a1000; frame = (0 132; 342 44); text = '2014'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400022ec20>>
```

My code is this,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView==_year01) {
    return [year1Array count];
}else if (tableView == _carTable){
    return [carArray count];
}
return YES;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (tableView == _year01){
    cell.textLabel.text=[year1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else if (tableView == _carTable){
    cell.textLabel.text=[carArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];


 return cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Cell %@",selectedCell);
if (tableView == _year01){
    self.year1.text=[year1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.year01.hidden=YES;
}else{
    self.carName.text=[carArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _carTable.hidden=YES;
    [_carName resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

Code to manage spaces in textfield is this,

```
-(void)textFieldDidChanges :(UITextField *)theTextField{
result=self.carName.text;
result=[result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSLog(@"RRR %@",result);
//just use this result where you want
}
```

Sending data to the next view,

```
- (IBAction)okay:(id)sender {

if ([_carName.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_year1.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_year2.text isEqualToString:@""] ) {

    NSString *message = @"Fill all the fields";

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Data"
                                                                   message:message
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    int duration = 2; // duration in seconds

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });


    _guideView.hidden=YES;
}else{

NSString *strAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",_year1.text,_year2.text];
NSLog(@"%@",strAppend);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:result forKey:@"name"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strAppend forKey:@"year"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

}
```

Comment: You have printed the selectedCell so it prints out the UITableviewCell instance. Can you please explain more context like which is your textfield and what do you really want to achieve.

Comment: Self.carName is mu textfield when I click on it and try to write any car name it shows me list  of cars in tableview, now when I select any car name from table view it shows that name on text field but when I send it the value goes the two or three words which I wrote first. @RozarioRapheal

Comment: You can try clearing the textfield by textField.text = "" and then set the carname.

Comment: I don't know why but let try `else if (tableView == _carTable)` instead of `else` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: where to clear the textfield? @RozarioRapheal

Comment: Its not working with ur answer. @Scott.N

Comment: clear both the textfields before the if statement.

Comment: Not working bro. @RozarioRapheal

Comment: <UITableViewCell: 0x7f9dad0a1000; frame = (0 132; 342 44); text = '2014'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400022ec20>>
This comes in console,because of NSLog(@"Cell %@",selectedCell);

Comment: Please explain your question further more, the info is insufficient.

Comment: What the arrays you are getting your data from?

Comment: Actually I have textfield in which user can enter car name, when user type Ho it shows the list of car with name starting with Honda, when we select any Honda car from list it show that in textfield which I send it to the API as a parameter, Now issue is coming that when I type HO it shows list and I select a car but when it send it to the API it contain only HO instead of full name. @HarminderSingh

Answer (score 0):

Empty your text field before assigning a new value in didSelectRow.

```
if (tableView == _year01)
{
   self.year1.text=@"";

   self.year1.text=[year1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   self.year01.hidden=YES;
}
else
{
   self.carName.text=@"";

   self.carName.text=[carArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   _carTable.hidden=YES;
  [_carName resignFirstResponder];
```

}

Comment: Not working bro, when I hit selected cell data it shows data in field but the starter words r send to the API.@Harminder Singh

Comment: Then you are missing something that you should include in the question.
Try to edit your question with more code,So that other can get a clear picture of the doubt you have.

Comment: Because by the info you have provided, this should be the solution.

Comment: I have edited question please check it. @Harminder Singh

Comment: do this in your textFieldDidChanges
result= theTextField.text;

Comment: Not working again same thing happening. @Harminder Singh

Comment: have you tried storing the selected value in NSString an then using it further? rather then using the textfield.text directly.

Comment: When I type any value with space it shows %20 instead of space and when it takes value from table view list it does not show %20 .  I have stored the textfield text in NSString *result. variable. @Harminder Singh