# Passing value from Table View to textfield in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a textfield in my view controller, in which when user type car name it shows related car name list in table view and user can select the any car from table view. If car name has space between name for example: "Honda Civic" the space is replaced by %20 and becomes "Honda%20Civic" and it pass value from textfield to the API.Now I'm getting an issue that when I type any letter like ho it shows list of cars of Honda when I select any car it comes textfield text , when I send the textfield value it goes to ho instead of the name I have selected from table view. How can I send it to the API the name of car I have selected from tableview list? 
My code to replaced space by %20 is this,

```
-(void)textFieldDidChanges :(UITextField *)theTextField{
result=theTextField.text;
NSLog(@"XXX%@",result);
result=[result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSLog(@"VVV %@",result);
//just use this result where you want
}
```

This is table view methods,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView==_year01) {
    return [year1Array count];
}else{
    return [carArray count];
}
return YES;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


if (tableView == _year01){
    cell.textLabel.text=[year1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else{
    cell.textLabel.text=[carArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];


return cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Cell %@",selectedCell);

if (tableView == _year01){
    self.year1.text=@"";
    self.year1.text=[year1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.year01.hidden=YES;
}else{
    self.carName.text=@"";
    self.carName.text=[carArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _carTable.hidden=YES;
    [_carName resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

This is I'm storing in NSUserdefault and passing to next view,

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:result forKey:@"name"];` [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`
```

The value in result come the letter I write instead of the value selected from table view list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textfield issue in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691497/textfield-issue-in-ios)

Comment: Your query is still not clear to me, can you please be a little more specific? @Faheem

Comment: Let me explain u that I have textfield when I type a name myself like Honda Civic as this word contain a space in it so I replace space by %20 and it is shown like Honda%20Civic. But when I select any value from table view also contain space but that word when send to API it does not contain space. I have type a word h and o and it shows me list of car staring with name h so I select a car name and it shows fine on textfield but when I pass the value of textfield it shows h and o word only instead of whole word. @iPeter

Comment: why you actually replace the space while typing the text field, you only have to replace the space while calling the api.

Comment: I didn't get it what r u saying? @SuryaSubenthiran

Comment: what is the reason you are changing the space with "%20" every time when user type the space?

Comment: It is storing like this scenario in database, so I have to follow this. @SuryaSubenthiran

Comment: the url with the space in invalid. so we have to add "%20" instead of space in url to make it valid. In server side when they parse the url parameters, the "%20" again converted to space automatically. So other than constructing the url you should not use "%20" conversion anywhere else.

Comment: Its not about url I'm passing the value from carName textfield to another view where I'm passing the value as parameter in API. @SuryaSubenthiran

Comment: Show me the code where you are sending the selected value to server. @Faheem

Comment: Its like this, NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"name"];
NSString *url=@"http://api.guardautozone.com.pk/?make=";
    NSString *string3 = [url stringByAppendingString:savedValue]; . @iPeter

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which place you used NSUserDeafults. store textfield did end finishing
        `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textfield.text forKey:@"name"];`

Comment: The issue is not in storing I thing issue is in getting the value it is passing value in result variable which I type manually instead of select from table view . @y.narasimha

Comment: the selected car will be showing in textfield,so you will store that value in  textfield did end finishing

Comment: how to do that?@y.narasimha

Comment: i have one doubt, you are displaying the table view value in textfield are not

Comment: I want user to type word and it should get list of related word in table view and when I select it it shows that name in textfield text but when try to send to another view controller it sends the words instead of selected item from table view.@narasimha

Comment: save that text in textfield delegate: UItextfield DidEndEditing [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textfield.text forKey:@"name"];

Comment: can u edit this in ur answer I'm not getting it. @narasimha

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, saving something in user defaults just for reading it on the same controller is unnecessary. Why you just don't use dependency injection if you are using segue? Creating one global object in that class that will contain value that you want to send is just enough if you're not. User defaults are more used for getting some info after termination of the as a lightweight info.

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, string) NSString *carYear;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Cell %@",selectedCell);

if (tableView == _year01){
    self.year1.text=@"";
    self.year1.text=[year1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.carYear = [carArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.year01.hidden=YES;
}else{
    self.carName.text=@"";
    self.carName.text=[carArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //This will have stored name
    _carTable.hidden=YES;
    [_carName resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

And after this just if you are using pass that value as:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self.carYear];
```

OR:

```
YourVCToPassValue *vc = [YourVCTOPassValue new];
vc.valueToBePassed = self.carYear;
```